# JavaScript changing object list to array. return undefined

Tags: javascript, return

```
function listToArray(list){
    var newArray = [];
    repeat();
    function repeat(){
        newArray.push(list.value);
        if(list.rest == null){
            return obj = newArray; // I don't know why It returns undefined here
        }
        else {
        list = list.rest;
        repeat();
        }
    }
}

// and this will return an array

function reTurn(){
    var listVar = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    return obj = listVar;
}
```

This function does change my obj when I look for it in console, but returns undefined.
Anyone can help me? please

Comment: function `listToArray()` doesn't return anything - only `repeat()` does. You have to `return repeat();` if you want to have something out of `listToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

just `return newArray` - you can't return an assignment like that.

Comment: Why can't you ?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the inner function, not the outer one. Add a `return newArray` to the bottom of `listToArray`. Change the `return` statement in `repeat` to just `return;`.

```
function listToArray(list){
    var newArray = [];
    repeat();

    function repeat(){
        newArray.push(list.value);
        if (list.rest) {
            list = list.rest;
            repeat();
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

There's nothing really wrong with the recursive approach, but it's not necessary. You could just as easily write

```
function listToArray(list){
    var newArray = [];

    while (list) {
      newArray.push(list.value);
      list = list.rest;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

However, even this code has the drawback that it is mixing the traversal of the list with the building of the array of values. It would be better to separate those:

```
function traverseList(list, fn) {
  while (list) {
    fn(list.value);
    list = list.rest);
  }
}
```

Now you can write `listToArray` as

```
function listToArray(list) {
    var newArray = [];

    traverseList(list, value => newArray.push(value));

    return newArray;
}
```

I might also write this as a generator:

```
function* forList(list) {
  while (list) {
    yield list.value;
    list = list.rest;
  }
}
```

Now I don't even need a separate function to create the array of values, because I can just write

```
[...forList(list)]
```